# Phoenix test suite can't find column when running test

Tags: testing, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm building my first phoenix test. I'm just trying to assert that there is content on the screen. I'm using `ex_machina` for a factory, that may be my problem but I'm not sure? Here is my code.

Table:

```
create table(:locations) do
  add :start,  :string
  add :finish, :string
end
```

Test:

```
defmodule AwesomeLunch.LocationsControllerTest do
  use AwesomeLunch.ConnCase

  import AwesomeLunch.Factory

  test "shows start and finish for locations" do
    conn = conn()
    locations = insert(:locations)

    conn = get conn, locations_path(conn, :show, locations.id)

    assert html_response(conn, 200) =~ locations.start
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
def show(conn, %{"id" => locations_id}) do
  locations = Repo.get!(Locations, locations_id)

  render conn, "show.html", locations: locations
end
```

Error:

```
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR (undefined_column): column "finish" of relation "locations" does not exist
 stacktrace:
   (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:463: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.struct/6
   (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:397: Ecto.Repo.Schema.apply/4
   (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:193: anonymous fn/11 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.do_insert/4
   (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:124: Ecto.Repo.Schema.insert!/4
   test/controllers/locations_controller_test.exs:8: (test)
```

Comment: You can try recreate database for test environment. Then recheck whether or not database table `locations` column `finish` exists.

Comment: How do I recreate the db?

Comment: `MIX_ENV=test mix ecto.drop`  OR `psql -U postgres -c "DROP DATABASE awesome_lunch_test;"`. In second approach you may have different database user name and database name (test configs are stored in `config/test.exs`). Then just run tests - database will be created before tests run.

Comment: Did you edit the migration to add `finish` later than you did `start`?

Comment: If you use `mix ecto.create.migration <x>`, then run the tests, then edit the migration file to create your column, then your database considers this migration run although your modifications haven't been taken in account. If this is your case, just run `MIX_ENV=test mix ecto.reset` and all migration will be re-run.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone! You were all correct.

Comment: @AlexHv you should add that as an answer :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Running `mix test` runs the migrations.

Here is possibly what happened:

1. You created a migration file with `mix ecto.gen.migration`.
2. You ran `mix test`. At this point, all migration were run, including your newly created one. This new migration was set as run in the `schema_migrations` table of your test db.
3. You edited your migration with an instruction to add a table.
4. You ran the `mix test` again: at this point mix saw no new migration to run, as the new one was already set as run. Your new column was never added.

If this is your case, just run `MIX_ENV=test mix ecto.reset` and all migration will be re-run. (data will also be lost, which shouldn't be a problem for a test db).

===

Tip : you can understand why migrations are run by looking at your `mix.exs` file in the `aliases` private function :

```
  defp aliases do
    [...
     "test": ["ecto.create --quiet", "ecto.migrate", "test"]]
  end
```

Comment: Ahhh thanks for this.  This fixed my issue even when 'MIX_ENV=test mix ecto.rollback' did not.